# AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'post'

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm writing pytest tests for my FastAPI async project. Tests causes error :

```
test_main.py::test_create_user FAILED                                    [100%]
test_main.py:32 (test_create_user)
client = <async_generator object client at 0x106585fc0>
generate_random_phone_number = <function generate_random_phone_number.<locals>._generate at 0x104ae4220>
generate_random_phone_prefix = <function generate_random_phone_prefix.<locals>._generate at 0x10654ac00>

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_create_user(client: AsyncClient, generate_random_phone_number, generate_random_phone_prefix):
        user_data = {
            "phone_number": generate_random_phone_number(),
            "phone_prefix": generate_random_phone_prefix()
        }
    
>       response = await client.post("/api/user/", json=user_data)
E       AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'post'

test_main.py:40: AttributeError
```

Here is code

```
import random
import string

import pytest
from httpx import AsyncClient

from main import app  # Make sure this import points to your FastAPI app instance

@pytest.fixture
async def client():
    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as client:
        yield client

@pytest.fixture
def generate_random_phone_number():
    def _generate(length=10):
        return ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=length))

    return _generate

@pytest.fixture
def generate_random_phone_prefix():
    def _generate():
        prefix_length = random.randint(1, 3)
        return '+' + ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=prefix_length))

    return _generate

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_create_user(client: AsyncClient, generate_random_phone_number, generate_random_phone_prefix):
    user_data = {
        "phone_number": generate_random_phone_number(),
        "phone_prefix": generate_random_phone_prefix()
    }

    response = await client.post("/api/user/", json=user_data)

    assert response.status_code == 201
    data = response.json()
    assert data["phone_number"] == user_data["phone_number"]
    assert data["phone_prefix"] == user_data["phone_prefix"]

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_duplicate_user(generate_random_phone_number, generate_random_phone_prefix):
    phone_number = generate_random_phone_number()
    phone_prefix = generate_random_phone_prefix()
    user_data = {
        "phone_number": phone_number,
        "phone_prefix": phone_prefix
    }

    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as ac:
        await ac.post("/api/user/", json=user_data)
        response = await ac.post("/api/user/", json=user_data)

    assert response.status_code == 400
    data = response.json()
    assert data["detail"] == "A user with the given phone number and prefix already exists."
```

changing the code to

```
import random
import string

import pytest
from httpx import AsyncClient

from main import app  # Make sure this import points to your FastAPI app instance

@pytest.fixture
def generate_random_phone_number():
    def _generate(length=10):
        return ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=length))

    return _generate

@pytest.fixture
def generate_random_phone_prefix():
    def _generate():
        prefix_length = random.randint(1, 3)
        return '+' + ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=prefix_length))

    return _generate

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_create_user(generate_random_phone_number, generate_random_phone_prefix):
    user_data = {
        "phone_number": generate_random_phone_number(),
        "phone_prefix": generate_random_phone_prefix()
    }

    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as ac:
        response = await ac.post("/api/user/", json=user_data)

    assert response.status_code == 201
    data = response.json()
    assert data["phone_number"] == user_data["phone_number"]
    assert data["phone_prefix"] == user_data["phone_prefix"]

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_duplicate_user(generate_random_phone_number, generate_random_phone_prefix):
    phone_number = generate_random_phone_number()
    phone_prefix = generate_random_phone_prefix()
    user_data = {
        "phone_number": phone_number,
        "phone_prefix": phone_prefix
    }

    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as ac:
        await ac.post("/api/user/", json=user_data)
        response = await ac.post("/api/user/", json=user_data)

    assert response.status_code == 400
    data = response.json()
    assert data["detail"] == "A user with the given phone number and prefix already exists."
```

works perfectly.

What is wrong with the first part of code?

Comment: I guess because you made a fixture out of an async function. How is that supposed to work? I don't know whether there is an async version of fixtures in the async pytest library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74351637/pytest-with-async-tests-test-setup-before-and-after - you might have to use `pytest_asyncio.fixture` - not sure if this is still the case.