TypeError: object async_generator can't be used in 'await' expression when using pytest async factory fixture
I'm trying to define an async factory fixture that creates a ReconnectingConsumer object and then awaits it to stop, like this:
@pytest.fixture
def make_consumer():
    async def _make_consumer():
        consumer = ReconnectingConsumer(
            amqp_url=AMQP_URL, queue=INPUT_QUEUE, on_message=None
        )
        yield consumer
        await consumer.stop()

    return _make_consumer

However, when I invoke it in my test case:
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_pending_todo_set(make_consumer, make_publisher, make_dispatcher_service):
    consumer_1 = await make_consumer()

I get the following error:
    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_pending_todo_set(make_consumer):
>       consumer_1 = await make_consumer()
E       TypeError: object async_generator can't be used in 'await' expression


Please try if this works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74352786/5378816
